# Unable to create filterPolicy on DVS port on vCenter (VMWare)

Tags: python, vmware, vcenter

I am tring to make script controlling firewall rules on DVS ports.
Here is my script(I have tried to post only relevant part, but even it big enough):

```
#!/usr/bin/evn python

import sys
import pprint

from oslo.vmware import api as vmware_api
from oslo.vmware import vim_util


vcenter_host = 'vcenter-hostname.tld'
vcenter_login = 'login'
vcenter_password = 'password'
vcenter_retry_count = 4
vcenter_retry_interval = 2


def main():
    vcenter = _make_connect()
    dvs = _lookup_dvs(vcenter, 'dvSwitch')
    port = _lookup_dvs_port(vcenter, dvs, '4853')

    spec_factory = vcenter.vim.client.factory

    port_spec = spec_factory.create('ns0:DVPortConfigSpec')
    port_spec.operation = 'edit'
    port_spec.key = port.key
    port_spec.configVersion = port.config.configVersion
    port_spec.setting = port_setting = spec_factory.create('ns0:DVPortSetting')

    port_setting.filterPolicy = filter_policy = spec_factory.create(
        'ns0:DvsFilterPolicy')

    filter_policy.filterConfig.append(spec_factory.create(
        'ns0:DvsTrafficFilterConfig'))
    filter_policy.inherited = False

    filter_config = filter_policy.filterConfig[0]
    filter_config.agentName = "custom-dvs-firewall-agent"
    filter_config.inherited = False
    filter_config.trafficRuleset = traffic_ruleset = spec_factory.create(
        'ns0:DvsTrafficRuleset')

    traffic_ruleset.enabled = True
    traffic_ruleset.rules.append(spec_factory.create('ns0:DvsTrafficRule'))

    rule = traffic_ruleset.rules[0]
    rule.description = "Port rule 0"
    rule.sequence = 10
    rule.direction = "incomingPackets"
    rule.action = spec_factory.create('ns0:DvsDropNetworkRuleAction')
    rule.qualifier.append(spec_factory.create('ns0:DvsIpNetworkRuleQualifier'))

    match = rule.qualifier[0]
    match.protocol = proto = spec_factory.create('ns0:IntExpression')

    proto.value = 6
    proto.negate = False

    match.destinationIpPort = port = spec_factory.create('ns0:DvsSingleIpPort')

    port.portNumber = 50001
    port.negate = False

    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    task = vcenter.invoke_api(
        vcenter.vim,
        'ReconfigureDVPort_Task',
        dvs, port=[port_spec]
    )
    result = vcenter.wait_for_task(task)
    pprint.pprint(result)


def _make_connect():
    return vmware_api.VMwareAPISession(
        vcenter_host,
        vcenter_login,
        vcenter_password,
        vcenter_retry_count,
        vcenter_retry_interval)


def _lookup_dvs(vcenter, name):
    network_folder = _lookup_net_folder(vcenter)
    networks = vcenter.invoke_api(
        vim_util, 'get_object_property', vcenter.vim,
        network_folder, 'childEntity').ManagedObjectReference

    for dvs in _filter_objects_by_type(
            networks, 'VmwareDistributedVirtualSwitch'):
        dvs_name = vcenter.invoke_api(
            vim_util, 'get_object_property',
            vcenter.vim, dvs, 'name')
        if dvs_name != name:
            continue

        break
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('DVS name=="{}" not found'.format(name))
    return dvs


def _lookup_dvs_port(vcenter, dvs, port_key):
    spec_factory = vcenter.vim.client.factory

    criteria = spec_factory.create(
        'ns0:DistributedVirtualSwitchPortCriteria')
    criteria.portKey = port_key

    try:
        port = vcenter.invoke_api(
            vcenter.vim, 'FetchDVPorts', dvs, criteria=criteria)[0]
    except IndexError:
        raise RuntimeError('DVS port key=="{}" not found'.format(port_key))
    return port


def _lookup_net_folder(vcenter):
    dc = _lookup_datacenter(vcenter)
    return vcenter.invoke_api(
        vim_util, 'get_object_property', vcenter.vim,
        dc, 'networkFolder')


def _lookup_datacenter(vcenter):
    return vcenter.invoke_api(
        vim_util, 'get_objects', vcenter.vim,
        'Datacenter', 100, ['name']).objects[0].obj


def _filter_objects_by_type(sequence, value):
    return (obj for obj in sequence
            if obj._type == value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_dev_/dvs-port-filterPolicy.py", line 137, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "_dev_/dvs-port-filterPolicy.py", line 70, in main
    result = vcenter.wait_for_task(task)
  File "/home/dbogun/.venv/cisco0-neutron/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_vmware/api.py", line 380, in wait_for_task
    return evt.wait()
  File "/home/dbogun/.venv/cisco0-neutron/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/event.py", line 121, in wait
    return hubs.get_hub().switch()
  File "/home/dbogun/.venv/cisco0-neutron/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 294, in switch
    return self.greenlet.switch()
  File "/home/dbogun/.venv/cisco0-neutron/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_vmware/common/loopingcall.py", line 76, in _inner
    self.f(*self.args, **self.kw)
  File "/home/dbogun/.venv/cisco0-neutron/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_vmware/api.py", line 397, in _poll_task
    'info')
  File "/home/dbogun/.venv/cisco0-neutron/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_vmware/api.py", line 341, in invoke_api
    return _invoke_api(module, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dbogun/.venv/cisco0-neutron/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_vmware/api.py", line 122, in func
    return evt.wait()
  File "/home/dbogun/.venv/cisco0-neutron/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/event.py", line 121, in wait
    return hubs.get_hub().switch()
  File "/home/dbogun/.venv/cisco0-neutron/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 294, in switch
    return self.greenlet.switch()
  File "/home/dbogun/.venv/cisco0-neutron/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_vmware/common/loopingcall.py", line 123, in _inner
    idle = self.f(*self.args, **self.kw)
  File "/home/dbogun/.venv/cisco0-neutron/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_vmware/api.py", line 95, in _func
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dbogun/.venv/cisco0-neutron/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_vmware/api.py", line 324, in _invoke_api
    raise clazz(six.text_type(excep), excep.details)
oslo_vmware.exceptions.VMwareDriverException: The object has already been deleted or has not been completely created
Cause: Server raised fault: 'The object has already been deleted or has not been completely created'
Faults: [ManagedObjectNotFound]
Details: {'obj': 'task-5189'}
```

PortGroup config's trafficFilterOverrideAllowed option must be set to True. Or you get "oslo_vmware.exceptions.VMwareDriverException: A specified parameter was not correct.\nfilterPolicy". What is completely unusable and give absolutely no information about real problem.

Can point me on error in my understanding of this task? Or maybe someone have example of similar script?

PS: vCenter v5.5

Answer (score 0):

You have to set:

```
filter_config.agentName = "dvfilter-generic-vmware"
```

I don't know why, but only with this agent name dvs apply ACL rules.